# Dereferencing a pointer to integer causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>


void PassByValue(int num) {
    std::cout << "inside PassByValue function" << std::endl;
}

void PassByRef(int &num) {
    std::cout << "inside PassByRef function " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value of num is: " << num << std::endl;
    num = 50;
    std::cout << "value of num is: "<< num << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int num1;
    int* pNum;
    num1 = 3;
    *pNum = 5;
    std::cout << "pNum is: " << *pNum << std::endl;
    PassByValue(num1);  
    PassByRef(*pNum);
}
```

this is my code and this console out line in the main function with the deferring is causing the problem. I'm little confused here. Did i do something wrong with the assignment? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You are dereferencing `pNum` without setting it to point to anything valid. That's cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: Perhaps you meant instead to write:  int* pNum = &num1;     .... that way when you set *pNum = 5, it would actually set num1 to 5 rather than crashing

Comment: @RSahu what about this line *pNum = 5;

Comment: @JeremyFriesner i actually want to store 5 to the location pointed by pNum.

Comment: @NoMan in the code you have posted, pNum is not pointing to any well-defined location, hence the crash you were seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*pNum = 5;` - `pNum` is uninitialized!
You need to have `pNum` point to some real memory first.
For instance:

```
pNum = new int();
*pNum = 5;
....
// Or:
int num2;
pNum = &num2;
*pNum = 5;
....
```